# How to send Dynamodb query results to browser encrypted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, encoding, amazon-dynamodb

I have a tiny table (100 records) that I keep in my Dynamodb backend. My web app will scan table at the beginning of the session. And then users will query this data with different parameters. My intention is not to go my backend for each query and do it on client side(front end) for better performance.

But because I don't want anyone to see my tiny table's data I would like to encrypt it while sending and decrypt it on browser side after arrival. I'm using Nodejs, dynamodb and API gateways as backend (AWS serverless architecture).

I'm a newbie and was wondering if it is possible and what the best practices are.

I'll give an example to describe my concern better. Imagine skyscanner keeps all airline-flight-ticketprice data in one table. they will have 2 options to let everbody to search publicly. First they can let users to query the table everytime they search (which will be slow). Second they can scan the table's data and send it to browser and users can search flights much faste on front end (with arrays etc..). I want to implement the 2nd approach but I also want to keep my data encrypted so nobody can copy my data and create a very similar website :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Cognito Identity Pools**

You can achieve this with authentication using [AWS Cognito Identity Pool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html)(Granting who can access which DynamoDB Table and even which Partition key) and using [AWS JavaScript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html) which uses SSL to encrypt the communication between the browser and DynamoDB.

Note: You can also use [AWS Cognito UserPools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html) if you don't have a user store which can be connected to Cognito Identity Pool.

**Using API Gateway and Lambda endpoint for Temporary Access Credentials**

If you already have an existing authentication mechanism you can use a API Gateway and Lambda endpoint where the Lambda function will have the code to assume an IAM Role and send the temporary access credentials to the browser. Then in the browser you can use AWS SDK for JavaScript to access DynamoDB.

Comment: I'll give an example to describe my concern better. Imagine skyscanner keeps all airline-flight-ticketprice data in one table. they will have 2 options to let everbody to search publicly. First they can let users to query the table everytime they search (which will be slow). Second they can scan the table's data and send it to browser and users can search flights much faste on front end (with arrays etc..). I want to implement the 2nd approach but I also want to keep my data encrypted so nobody can copy my data and create a very similar website :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo app that does specifically what you're looking for...once logged in, the user has access to his own "row" in dynamoDB...

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cognito-angular-quickstart

Here's what you get by running the install script (it creates all of the resources for you):
http://cognito.budilov.com

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vladimir. I added an example of what I need. I realize that it wasnt clear enough.